# intrinsicContentSize.width's value is greater than specified widthAnchor

Tags: swift, autolayout, uikit, constraints, uilabel

I have a UILabel, and I've added leading, trailing, top, bottom, width, and height autolayout constraints to it, for some reason during runtime, the value of intrinsicContentSize is greater than what I specified for widthAnchor with 1000 priority.

I've attached a screenshot for more details:

[image]

Note:

The frame for the UILabel is set to .zero since I'm using Auto layout, and yes, the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is set to false.

How can I get the contentSize(intrinsicContentSize) to be equal to the constraints that I'm specifying?

Answer (score 0):

After posting the same question on multiple forums, here is the explanation I received.

the leading, and trailing constraints wanted the width of the `UILabel` to be equal to 365.25, but, the insintricContentSize was rounding it up to `365.5` for some unknown reason, maybe because it was a quarter pixel, or something.

What I did to fix it is:

The way I got `365.25` was `UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.95`, I changed this equation to `ceil(UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.95)`, so that is is rounding up, and we have a full pixel instead of a quarter.

This in my case fixed the problem, Apple doesn't really specify this rule in their layout engine documentation, hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Cheers.